# Reference files in .msi in Wix installer

Tags: c#, wix, installation

I have an .MSI that I created using WIX.  It is for a C# project I developed in VS2012.  When I give a client my MSI file, I expect to have the MSI reference itself, and "place/deploy" a set of files to a location that the customer specifies.

I set the location of all these files to

```
$(sys.CURRENTDIR)Build\etc\etc
```

However, this variable is resolved on build, so it is hard-coded to MY directory on my dev machine.  It is now getting set during run-time and using the current MSI's location to pull the files.

This has got to be possible...but I can't find the solution anywhere, any help?

Comment: It looks like you need to include a WiX UI that allows the user to specify the install location. You probably need a UI of WiUI_FeatureTree and then specify your directories like this http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixui/dialog_reference/wixui_installdir.html

Answer (score 0):

Your xml should be structured some what like this:

```
<Media Id="1" Cabinet="media1.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
   <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
     <Directory Id="COMPANYDIR" Name="MyCompany">
      <Directory Id="PRODUCTDIR" Name="MyProduct">
        <Component Id="C.AppExe" Guid="SOME GUID" >
          <File Id="AppExe" Name="MyApp.exe"
              Source="$(sys.CURRENTDIR)Build\etc\etc"/>
         </Component>
       </<Directory>
      </<Directory>
   </<Directory>
</<Directory>
```